# My iOS App target deleted by mistake

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I deleted my App target in iOS by mistake. It made me get the old version and replace the classes again and build it which is quiet risky. Is there an easy way to add a target to the app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057453/how-to-retrive-accidentally-deleted-app-target-from-xcode)

Comment: I tried the solution from the page above. But All i got was just a blank screen after adding the new view. Which is the reason i started a new thread. Thanks.

Comment: any version controlling...?

Comment: This was a very short project so didn't have version controlling. But Only after this mistake i have learnt how important it is to maintain the project in an SVN or Git.

Comment: Seriously... CMD-Z doesn't work?  What an awful awful awful design ... ugh...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check all the **Answers** from this SO Question : [How to recreate a deleted target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237006/how-to-recreate-a-deleted-target)

Preferred One is the Answer given by **Joshua Nozzi**.

Comment: They seem to be working fine for the mac applications, but mine is an iOS app.

Comment: Good one #Bhavin. Thanks